# Discount amount is not showing on cart page

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, cart, discount

In cart page (mysite.com/checkout/cart), there is a section that shows as **Summary**. In this section, usually displayed as,
a section to *Estimate Shipping and Tax* and after that, sections for

1. Subtotal
2. Discount
3. Tax

amounts. But in my site, the discount is not displayed. How can I display the discount amount and code as default magento 2 do?
I tried checking **checkout_cart_index.xml** but cannot find any abnormalities.

Can please someone help me?

Comment: Discount displaying by default Magento.

Comment: @SureshChikani yes.but in my theme it didn't. I fixed it by adding Magento_SalesRule to my theme. I've another problem now. Calculated discount amount displayed is wrong. why is that?